# Why does form success message display only once on submit?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the form below, I have a simple form. First Name, Last Name and Gender are the only required fields. Once those fields are complete, click submit... the **First Name** and **Last Name** field inputs are collected and a message displays, (for example) **Joe Smith has been added.**, and the form resets and the message goes away.

When I try to add another person to the form and hit submit, the message doesn't display, but the form still resets after 2500ms.

**Why doesn't the success alert display beyond the first form submit?**

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('#addPerson');
const select = document.querySelector('select[name=gender]');
const personAdded = document.querySelector('#successAddPersonMsg');

submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (fname.value != "" && lname.value != "" && select.value != "") {
    document.querySelector(
      "#successAddPersonMsg"
    ).innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">${fname.value} ${lname.value} has been added!</div>`;

    setTimeout(function() {
      personAdded.style.display = "none";
      addNewPersonForm.reset();
    }, 2500);

    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel blank-panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form action="" name="addNewPersonForm" id="addNewPersonForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
                <label for="fname" class="is-required">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 m-t">
                <label for="lname" class="is-required">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="gender" class="is-required">Gender</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" required>
                  <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
                  <option value="1">Female</option>
                  <option value="2">Male</option>
                  <option value="3">Unspecified</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="birthDate" class="control-label">Birth</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="birthDateDiv">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" id="birthDate" name="birthDate">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 m-t">
                <label for="dummy" class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" id="addPerson" value="Add
                            Person">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-4">
      <div id="successAddPersonMsg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You never change `personAdded.style.display` from `none` back to `block`.

Comment: That was it... such a simple thing to miss. Thanks.